# Неприменение настроек main_activity на реальном устройстве

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-layout

Есть два main activity - одно для вертикальной, другое для горизонтальной ориентации. В эмуляторе все работает как надо, одна при работе на реальном устройстве верстка плывет (проверял на двух аппаратах с android 4.4.4 и 5.1.1). Как это исправить?

манифест

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/pomegranate">
    <activity android:name="hitrene.pomegranate.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="hitrene.pomegranate.Prefs"/>
</application>
```

land/activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Time"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:background="@drawable/start"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pauseButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:background="@drawable/stop"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
</ImageButton>
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Time"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="70dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stop"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/start"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

DEXP Ixion 4.5 LTE[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Genymotion Nexus 5x [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:** Ок, ответ частично найден. Все дело в манифесте, а именно в

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Тогда вопрос - как сохранить все данные, ибо у меня их прилично, а сохранение оповещений не работает при способе сохранения данных из .MainActivity

Comment: Какие данные?.. 0_о

Comment: Меня беспокоит оповещения, ибо при перевороте при отключении configChanges в манифесте их начинает неистово колбасить (появляется две надписи в течении одной секунды (одна о завершении или начале работы, а вторая показывает текущее время)).

Comment: Это отдельный вопрос, связанный с тем как вы оповещения показываете. Грубо говоря вам надо при их показе сначала проверить, не показываются ли они уже. Задайте это отдельным вопросом. А решение с разметкой перенесите тут в ответ. Принцип такой - одна проблема-один вопрос-один ответ.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб хорошо, спасибо